# Advanced string manipulation from job online

Tags: java, string

I just did a company online and i couldnt get this question right..

looking to improve for next online assessment.

question is:
your given 1 input string where the format is like this:

current:target

```
   where current = Company,Stock or Bond,amount

   and target = Company,Stock or Bond,amount
```

and the ':' separates current and target

an example is:

```
    Vodafone,STOCK,10|Google,STOCK,15|Microsoft,BOND,15:Vodafone,STOCK,15|Google,STOCK,10|Microsoft,BOND,15
```

the output should be a string that makes the input meet the output for this case its going to be:

```
  SELL,Google,STOCK,5
  BUY,Vodafone,STOCK,5
```

as you can see the ouput should be in alphabetical order (google is before vodafone) and also bonds should appear before stocks.

here is some setup code to help you:

```
public class main {


    public static void main(String[] args){
        String input = "Vodafone,STOCK,10|Google,STOCK,15|Microsoft,BOND,15:Vodafone,STOCK,15|Google,STOCK,10|Microsoft,BOND,15";
        String output = matchBenchmark(input);
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    public static String matchBenchmark(String input){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably parse the input into a map:

- Map keys should be `<company>,<type>`
- Map values can be `{<current-value>,<new-value>}`

Then iterate over the map (you probably want to sort the keys) and print `SELL` or `BUY` according to the different between the current and new value.

Answer (score 0):

Smth. like that:

```
public final class Market {

    private final Pattern patternLine = Pattern.compile("(?<current>.+):(?<target>.+)");
    private final Pattern patternData = Pattern.compile("(?<name>\\w+),(?<active>\\w+),(?<amount>[-]?\\d+)");
    private final Pattern patternDataSplit = Pattern.compile("\\|");

    public String matchBenchmark(String input) {
        Matcher matcher = patternLine.matcher(input);

        if (!matcher.matches())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        Map<String, Data> current = getData(matcher.group("current"));
        Map<String, Data> target = getData(matcher.group("target"));

        return calc(current, target).stream()
                                    .map(data -> data.getName() + ',' + data.getActive() + ',' + data.getAmount())
                                    .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
    }

    private Map<String, Data> getData(String str) {
        return Arrays.stream(patternDataSplit.split(str))
                     .map(patternData::matcher)
                     .filter(Matcher::matches)
                     .map(m -> new Data(m.group("name"), m.group("active"), Integer.parseInt(m.group("amount"))))
                     .collect(Collectors.toMap(Data::getName, Function.identity()));
    }

    private static final String BUY = "BUY";
    private static final String SELL = "SELL";

    private static Queue<Data> calc(Map<String, Data> current, Map<String, Data> target) {
        Queue<Data> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(Data.SORT_BY_NAME_ACTIVE_ASC);

        Set<String> names = new HashSet<>(current.keySet());
        names.addAll(target.keySet());

        for (String name : names) {
            Data dataCurrent = current.get(name);
            Data dataTarget = target.get(name);

            if (dataCurrent == null) {
                if (dataTarget.amount != 0)
                    queue.add(new Data(dataTarget.amount > 0 ? BUY : SELL, dataTarget.name, Math.abs(dataTarget.amount)));
            } else if (dataTarget == null) {
                if (dataCurrent.amount != 0)
                    queue.add(new Data(dataCurrent.amount > 0 ? SELL : BUY, dataCurrent.name, Math.abs(dataCurrent.amount)));
            } else if (dataCurrent.amount != dataTarget.amount)
                queue.add(new Data(dataTarget.amount > dataCurrent.amount ? BUY : SELL, dataCurrent.name,
                        Math.abs(dataTarget.amount - dataCurrent.amount)));
        }

        return queue;
    }

    public static final class Data {

        public static final Comparator<Data> SORT_BY_NAME_ACTIVE_ASC = Comparator.comparing(Data::getActive).thenComparing(Data::getName);

        private final String name;
        private final String active;
        private final int amount;

        public Data(String name, String active, int amount) {
            this.name = name;
            this.active = active;
            this.amount = amount;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getActive() {
            return active;
        }

        public int getAmount() {
            return amount;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @asasasdada this f. s. took 10 minutes of coding.

Comment: @oleg.cheredenik this was for an internship... im not sure theyre expecting us to know regex... let alone use priority queues streams hashmaps, pattern, match or whatever that is. isnt there an easier solution?